# Error when using setObject in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios5, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting the exception:

> -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

The offending line is:

```
[delegate.sharedData.dictFaves setObject:@"test" forKey:@"4"];
```

Delegate is initialized thus in MyViewController.m:

```
delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

This is how my delegate is defined in AppDelegate.h:

```
#import "CommonData.h"
...
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSString *tempFave;
    CommonData *sharedData;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *tempFave;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CommonData *sharedData;
```

sharedData is initialized in AppDelegate.m thus:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
...
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize sharedData;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    sharedData = [[CommonData alloc] init];
    return YES;
}
```

sharedData is defined in CommonData.h:

```
@interface CommonData : NSObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dictAffirms;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictFaves;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *dictAffirms;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *dictFaves;
```

shared data implementation file CommonData.m:

```
#import "CommonData.h"
...
@implementation CommonData

@synthesize dictAffirms;
@synthesize dictFaves;

@end
```

I have declared the members of CommonData to be Mutable. Apparently that is insufficient. What else must I do in order to write to the Dictionaries inside CommonData?

Comment: where do you alloc init the NSMutableDictionaries.  Also, those are ivars - are you exposing those as properties?

Comment: I edited my post to include the CommonData implementation. You will see there is NO constructor. So when the line 'sharedData=alloc/init', I have not written a constructor which includes NSMutableDictionary alloc/init. Is that the problem?

Comment: We don't generally use the term "constructor" in objective-c. It's called an initializer, or an -init method. You don't need to have an initializer. But if dictFaves is going to have a value in it, you must assign it one from somewhere. If you assign a non-mutable dictionary, you get this problem. Feel free to use the -mutableCopy method to convert an NSDictionary into an NSMutableDictionary (remember to autorelease copies when assigning to retained properties when not using ARC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this error before when trying to write to a dictionary that is filled from a plist. If you use

```
yourMutableDictionary = [someDataSource objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

your dictionary will be immutable, even if it is declared mutable. Use instead

```
yourMutableDictionary = [someDataSource mutableArrayValueForKey:@"someKey"];
```

and your problem will go away, assuming this *is* in fact your problem. It might be something like:

```
yourMutableDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

or

```
yourMutableDictionary = [NSDictionary new];
```

and you just are accidentally creating immutable objects, which is pretty much the same problem as above, just different.

It would be nice to see the code used to initialize the NSMutableDictionaries.

Edit: Maybe try something like this, as I'm curious as to what the results would be. Instead of using:

```
[delegate.sharedData.dictFaves setObject:@"test" forKey:@"4"];
```

try

```
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:delegate.sharedData.dictFaves];
[dict setObject:@"test" forKey:@"4"];
delegate.sharedData.dictFaves = dict;
[dict release];
```

Comment: please see my edit above. I included the entire .m file. You will see there is no initialization of the NSMutableDictionaries. So where do I init them: in the CommonData implementation file, or the Delegate class? I realize this is a dumb question, but I'm simply drawing a blank.

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the property for sharedDict?

Comment: I added the code which creates the property. I also fleshed out the other code more and regroued it. Hopefully it is now easier to read. Thanks for your interest thus far....

Comment: that code works.So this confirms that my dictFaves is NOT Mutable. So, is the code you provided acceptable to use in my app, or is it simply for debugging? I'd like to find & fix the cause so I can learn from it.

Comment: The code I provided is by all means acceptable for use in your app. If the dictionary in question contains a large amount of data, the difference in performance *might* be perceptible. But you shouldn't notice a difference. I would look at @Chuck's answer, as he seems to be the only one who has figured out the real problem here. But I'm happy to know my code helped.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the `dictFaves` to be mutable, but that doesn't mean you actually stored a mutable object in there. Check your initializer. You'll probably have something like the following:

```
dictFaves = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

If so, you need to change that to `NSMutableDictionary` instead.

Comment: @Yar: Current Clang will. GCC won't. The `+alloc` and `-init` methods are both declared with the `id` return type, so GCC won't care what type of variable you stuff it into (as long as it's an object/pointer). Clang is smart enough to know that `+alloc` and `-init` actually return the instance type of their receiver and should warn.

Comment: Great point, I was thinking `NSDictionary dictionary` but not all methods are interchangeable like that.

Comment: @Yar: Even that method is declared as returning `id`, so it still has a problem. Modern Clang actually has a feature that can fix this called [Related result types](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objc_instancetype), but I'm not sure whether that's supported in the clang shipping with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your property setter for the dictionary is declared as `copy`. NSMutableDictionary's `copy` method returns an immutable NSDictionary (in general, `copy` almost always returns an immutable object). So assuming you're using the standard synthesized setter, any time you set that property, you're assigning the wrong type behind the scenes. It should probably be `strong` instead.

Comment: Thanks - changing the NSDictionary property to ` (nonatomic, strong) ` did the trick.